# Is insulating the back of a PTAC unit for winter a good idea?

Tags: insulation, heating, winterizing

The winter heat in my apartment is supplied by old PTAC (Packaged Terminal Air Conditioner) units, using resistance heat (it's too cold for the heat pump to work). A lot of cold outside air leaks through the insides of these units. I was wondering whether putting insulation on the exterior side of each PTAC unit, so that the whole unit is completely insulated from the outside, is a good idea.

Obviously, I'd remove that rear insulation when the cooling function is needed in the summer.

My goal is to reduce heating bills.

EDIT (additional information):

Manufacturer: Islandaire
Model: EZ09HBRSC1A1XXY

I've tried to find the manual online but I couldn't (probably the model is too old), here's the closest I could find:
https://islandaire.com/pdf/units/EZSeries42manual.pdf

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's a PTAC; "something something air conditioner"? Do you have a make and model? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: "It's too cold for the heat pump to work" is a faulty assumption.  Thereafter, the idea crumbles.  It's too cold hour by hour and day by day.  How will you keep it from running in heat pump mode on a nice day?

Comment: @DanielGriscom Thank you for the pointer to the tour, I've edited my post to try to follow the recommendations. I've added the maker/model number, and a photo of the specs and the wiring diagram. PTAC is "Packaged Terminal Air Conditioner", and in the case of my unit, it contains an air conditioner/heat pump, and a backup resistance heater.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica From my observation, the heat pump doesn't seem to turn on. The manual (for a different model though) suggests that the heat pump turns on only if the external temperature is above 40F. The wiring diagram seems to suggest 38F. This is higher than a typical temperature where I live, especially at night (and for bedrooms at least this is when I need heat). As for how to technically prevent the heat pump from even trying to run, the unit has a switch that forces the heat pump off and uses resistance heating only.